# Why doesn't the shape of my numpy array change?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have made a numpy array out of data from an image. I want to convert the numpy array into a one-dimensional one.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as img

if __name__ == '__main__':

  my_image = img.imread("zebra.jpg")[:,:,0]
  width, height = my_image.shape
  my_image = np.array(my_image)
  img_buffer = my_image.copy()
  img_buffer = img_buffer.reshape(width * height)
  print str(img_buffer.shape)
```

The 128x128 image is here.

[image]

However, this program prints out (128, 128). I want `img_buffer` to be a one-dimensional array though. How do I reshape this array? Why won't numpy actually reshape the array into a one-dimensional array?

Comment: It looks like you have a color image, but you're only reading the red channel for each pixel of the image.  Is that your intention?

Comment: Thanks! My original intention is to read all of RGB. Why am I reading just the red channel?

Comment: @DavidFaux as wim said, since apparently you had quickly edited the question to have correct code, can you please change it back. Its utterly confusing to have a question "Why does this not work" with code that works.

Comment: @DavidFaux, `matplotlib.image.imread` returns a three-dimensional array.  The first two dimensions are the width and height of the image, and the last are the red, green, blue, and alpha channels for each pixel.  I think your code, specifically `img[:,:,0]`, is choosing every pixel, but *only the red channel*.  Check out http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) doesn't work in place.  Your code isn't working because you aren't assigning the value returned by `reshape` back to `img_buffer`.

If you want to flatten the array to one dimension, [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) might be easier options.

```
>>> img_buffer = img_buffer.ravel()
>>> img_buffer.shape
(16384,)
```

Otherwise, you'd want to do:

```
>>> img_buffer = img_buffer.reshape(np.product(img_buffer.shape))
>>> img_buffer.shape
(16384,)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
>>> img_buffer = img_buffer.reshape(-1)
>>> img_buffer.shape
(16384,)
```

Answer (score 8):

`.reshape` returns a new array, rather than reshaping in place.

By the way, you appear to be trying to get a bytestring of the image - you probably want to use `my_image.tostring()` instead.